# Store data into database using request json string in laravel

Tags: json, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a table name Student ( id , name , division ). To store data into this table I am sending json string as a request to the api in laravel.

**Request json string is,**

```
{
"name":"abc",
"division":"a",
"city":"xyz"
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
 public function registerStudent(Request $request){

    $requestData = $request->json()->all(); 
    $studentModel = Student::create($requestData);

 }
```

**Student Model**

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name','division'
    ];

   
}
```

When i execute this code , i get the following error,

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'city' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `Student`...
```

now my question here is, in what way I can store the data into database from json request with having extra keys into json object/array.

Comment: If the `id` column is set to auto-increment you don't need it in the `$fillable` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the collections [only](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only) method.

```
public function registerStudent(Request $request){

    $requestData = collect($request->json()->all())->only(['name', 'division']); 
    $studentModel = Student::create($requestData);

 }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate with my example

Comment: Absolutely, what specifically would you like me to elaborate on?

Comment: Also, do you need the extra data? Do you only want to store `id`, `name` & `division`?

Comment: yes i need extra data in api from user , but only name , division field will be used from request and city key will be used for other processes.

Comment: So `city` shouldn't be store when calling `Student::create`?

Comment: exactly,, city should not be stored in database becoz student table does not have any column name city.

Comment: my only concern is, is it possible in laravel to use only necessary fields and create table.

Comment: You could use the collections [only](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only) method. I'll update the example above.